# Wrapping and moving child nodes

Tags: xslt

could you please help me transforming the following snippet?

```
<root>
    <topic>                  <!-- First topic -->
        <p>content1</p>
        <topic>              <!-- Second topic -->
            <p>content2</p>
        </topic>
        <topic>              <!-- Third topic -->
            <p>content3</p>
        </topic>
    </topic>
</root>
```

I need to cut the second topic and the third topic off the first topic, wrap them in a **new**/**empty** topic and attach the new topic with its children to the root node.

```
<root>
    <topic>                   <!-- First topic -->
        <p>content1</p>
    </topic>
    <topic>                   <!-- New topic -->
        <topic>               <!-- Second topic -->
            <p>content2</p>   
        </topic>
        <topic>               <!-- Third topic -->
            <p>content3</p>
        </topic>
    </topic>
</root>
```

Maybe there is a very simple solution. I tried to prefix the second/suffix the third topic with a tag (looks like a very dirty solution to me), but I fail moving them.

```
<xsl:if test="position() = 1">
    <![CDATA[
    <topic>
    ]]>
    ...
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="position() = last()">
    ...
    <![CDATA[
    </topic>
    ]]>
</xsl:if>
```

**UPDATE 1**
This is a more complex and detailed example:

**Source - Before Transformation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <!--
    The root has only a 
    title and multiple child
    topics. but no other child
    elements.
  -->
  <title>Root</title>
  <topic id="topic_1">
    <!--
      Allowed child elements of 'topic'
      are listed in the DITA spec.:
      http://bit.ly/1ruYbdq
    -->
    <title>First Topic - First Level</title>
  </topic>
  <topic id="topic_2">
    <title>Second Topic - First Level</title>
    <!--
      This is the main problem.
      A topic must not contain
      child topics AND other child
      elements after the
      transformation.
      If a topic has child topic
      AND other child elements, the
      topics have to be extracted.
    -->
    <topic id="topic_3">
      <title>Third Topic - Second Level</title>
    </topic>
    <topic id="topic_4">
      <!--
        The number of topics is not limited.
      --> 
      <title>Fourth Topic - Second Level</title>
      <topic id="topic_5">
        <!--
          Third level topics have to
          be moved to the second
          hierarchy level. No topic
          may reside on the third
          level after transformation.
        -->
        <title>Fifth Topic - Third Level</title>
      </topic>
    </topic>
  </topic>
</root>
```

**Result - After Transformation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <title>Root</title>
  <topic id="topic_1">
    <title>First Topic - First Level</title>
  </topic>
  <topic id="topic_2">
    <title>Second Topic - First Level</title>
  </topic>
  <!--
    The third and fourth topic have
    been moved extracted from the
    second topic. Both (could be any
    number) have been wrapped with a
    dummy 'topic' element.
  -->

  <topic>
    <!-- 
      The second level topics have
      been wrapped with a "dummy"
      topic element.
    -->
    <topic id="topic_3">
      <title>Fourth Topic - Second Level</title>
    </topic>
    <topic id="topic_4">
      <title>Fifth Topic - Second Level</title>
    </topic>

    <topic id="topic_5">
      <!--
        The third level topic
        has been moved to the
        second hierarchy level.
        -->
      <title>Sixth Topic - Third Level</title>
    </topic>
  </topic>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this works for me:

```
<xsl:template match="//topic">
     <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="topic[not(topic)]">
             <!--
                 Wrap first level topics in a
                 single <section> element.
             -->
             <section>
                 <xsl:apply-templates/>
             </section>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
             <xsl:choose>
                 <!--
                     Wrap nested topics in a
                     <section> container.
                 -->
                 <xsl:when test="(count(preceding-sibling::topic) = 0) and (count(following-sibling::topic) >= 1)">
                     <!--
                         Close the section of the parent <topic> element.
                     -->
                     <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/section&gt;</xsl:text>
                     <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;section&gt;</xsl:text>
                     <section>
                         <xsl:apply-templates/>
                     </section>     
                 </xsl:when>
                 <xsl:otherwise>
                     <section>
                         <xsl:apply-templates/>
                     </section>                        
                 </xsl:otherwise>
             </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe there is a very simple solution.

Maybe there is, but it's difficult to see what's given here and what's just an example. Would this very simple solution work for you?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <topic>   
            <xsl:copy-of select="topic/p"/>
        </topic> 
        <topic>   
            <xsl:copy-of select="topic/topic"/>
        </topic> 
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, unfortunately it does not. I prepared a more complex example and its result.